# issue in laravel relationship search data

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, eloquent-relationship

**I want to search for usernames from the user's table.**

I have used the Laravel relationship(eloquent). I don't search for usernames from users' tables. My code is Below and here I Explain the relationship with  All Tablets

I have a query write inside the group controller

```
    public function getGroupsData(Request $request){
      $group = Group::with(['memberscount', 'getusername'])->where('groupName', "like", "%" . $request->searchText . "%")
        ->whereHas('getusername.user', function ($query) use ($request) {
            return $query->where('name', 'like', '%'. $request->searchText . '%');
           })
        ->get();
    }
```

**memberscount and getusername relationship write-in group model** my group model is below

```
class Group extends Model
{
    
    public function memberscount(){    
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Members', 'group_id', 'id')->where('memberStatus', 'Joined');
    }

    public function getusername(){    
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Members', 'group_id', 'id')->where('isOwner', 0);
    }
}
```

And user's table relationship in members models. members model is below

```
class Members extends Model
{   
    public function user(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id', 'user_id');
    }

    /**get group name */
    public function group(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Group', 'id', 'group_id');
    }
}
```

I have search user's data **this(user)** relationship. But I can't search data in a multilevel relationship.

Comment: I think you need to take a look at the documentation. search for `whereHas()`.

Comment: @GertB. I  have also try with whereHas() but not working

Comment: can you add the code you have tried. The problem is not clear at the moment

Comment: @GertB. I have added my tried code.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm the first step is to rename name relationships in class Group

I think it was more logical names

```
memberscount -> members
getusername -> owner
```

And the second step is to search. I write like this:

```php
$group = Group::whereHas('owner', function ($query) use ($request) {
 return $query->where('groupName', 'like', '%'. $request->searchText . '%');
})->get();
```

or more effective and clear code we can save in scope us query like that:

```php
$group = Group::whereHas('owner', function ($query) use ($request) {
 return $query->haveGroupName($request->searchText);
})->get();
```

In the **Group** model class write code like that:

```php
     /**
     * Scope a query to only have groupName.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
     * @param  string $param
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function scopeHaveGroupName($query, $param)
    {
        return $query->where('groupName', 'like', '%' . $param . '%');
    }
```

Comment: I have a search for groupName and userName. Only group names are searched in this solution. I want to search for groupnames and usernames. The username search relationship is in the members' model

Comment: @JinalGajera if you can add the search on groupname, the search on username is basically the same. The answer shows you how it's done.

Comment: @JinalGajera you can after close first `whereHas` add `->orWhereHas()` and again write new whereHas, but diffrent name relationships